# Use includes in .gitlab-ci.yml without direct user access to included project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

We are using [includes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html) from `project B` within `project A` within the `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follows:

```
include:
  - project: pathto/projectb
    file:
      - "/pathto/myfile.yml"
```

which works well when the user has access rights to both projects but breaks with a linting error when the user has only access rights for `project A`:

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:

    Project `pathto/projectb` not found or access denied! Make sure any includes in the pipeline configuration are correctly defined.
```

Now the problem is that we want to use the include (and pipeline to succeed) also when the user who starts the pipeline has only access rights to `project A`.

Are there any ways to achieve this?

Background: `Project B` holds some general CI files and the user is an external developer and should have limited access only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Users have to be able to read the yaml file in order to include it. Why is it a problem for users to be able to have read access to `Project B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for an `include:` from a project to work, the user that triggers the pipeline must have at least read access to the referenced CI YAML files.

You must either (1) make `Project B` have internal or public visibility or (2) provide membership access to users who trigger pipelines using includes in the project.

There may be ways you can separate the yaml files from `Project B` (like publishing them elsewhere), but in all cases, users can (must be able to) read all includable files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I like the idea of making a separate `Project C` with read access which should work for my case.